# How to adjust an angular2 frontend driven by RESTful services according to role of authenticated user

Tags: angular, authentication, frontend

I have developed a webapp in Angular 2, backed by a set of RESTful services. Those RESTful services are all secured, and each endpoint requires authenticated user with one or more user roles. Different services can have different roles.

To consume these services, the webapp first authenticates the user, then a received JWT-token is sent in each request to the services. This token contains all the information about the user, such as username, roles etc.

Now, how can I easily present **only** those elements in my webapp which the logged inn user has acccess to. Are there any standard ways to that? Or are there any best-practices for that? I want to avoid hard-coding stuff in my webapp as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you consider a feature element. There are few (or even more than that) approaches.

- show/hide based on JWT content. That can be done with a service such as `FeatureService` that has something like `isFeatureAvailable` method. then you can use `ngIf` to show/hide elements in the template or even do conditional checking in the code.
- if you use lazy-loading and each feature lives in their own lazy-loaded module, you could use `canActivate` feature of the router to prevent loading selected features

Hope that make sense

Comment: Interesting!! That does seem to be one sensible option; have one small and standalone service which will return what the user can do. Is the following plausible in terms of good architecture? This service is backed by a db, containing "endpoint of restful service", "http-method" (get/post), and "the roles" (or even users) which are allowed to "read" and/or "write". Then only one call to this service (with user/role as input) returns all the permissions. Do you have any recommendations in terms of tweaks to this?

Comment: We're using this approach (FeatureService and router's canActivate) in our production application and that works just fine. In terms of correctness, I think the important thing to remember that all security features should be implemented on the server side. Frontend should reflect some of those features to improve usability. Implementing real security in UI does not make sense because it is not secure anyway.

Comment: Yes, all the RESTful services are secured, this issue was raised just to find a good way of hiding elements in the GUI which doesn't make sense for the user in terms of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If I would have to do it, then I would divide the screen into businessEntities and privileges. There should be a REST API which will on the basis of the roles of the logged in user, send the Angular UI the combinations of valid BusinessEntities and Privileges. Based on this information you can show/hide components on the screen. A businessEntity can be a button, form, textbox etc and a Privilege can be Read/Write etc.

If it is a small application, then all this information of valid businessEntity/privilege combinations can go directly into the JWT to speed-up the application. But then if we have many such combinations then the JWT will be huge and this approach will not be recommended.

There can certainly be better ways of doing it, this is just my approach.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Interesting thought, but I think the businessEntities as you define them would make the security configuration very verbose. In addition, security should probably be defined such that non-developers can understand it easily. Understanding buttons, forms etc seems a little difficult.